# SwiftUI animations cancelled by keyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following view in SwiftUI:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TickerView: View {
    @State var appeared = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        let text = "rdvz"
        let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Inter-Bold", size: 14.0)!])
        let horizontalSpacing = textSize.width + 4
        
        GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0.0) {
                ForEach(0...Int(geometry.size.width / horizontalSpacing) + 2, id: \.self) {
                    index in
                    Text("rdvz")
                        .frame(width: horizontalSpacing)
                        .font(Font.DesignSystem.textSmBold)
                        .foregroundColor(index % 2 == 0 ? .fgSecondary700 : .fgTertiary600)
                }
            }
            .offset(x: appeared > 0 ? -horizontalSpacing * 2 : 0)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                    appeared = 1
                    print("withAnimation \(appeared)")
                }
            })
        })
        .frame(height: textSize.height)
    }
}
```

It creates a line of text that fills the entire width of its container and animates to the left forever:

[image]

But I notice that if this control is on the screen when the user opens the keyboard, the animation stops. Why does this happen and how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Using GeometryReader will cause the available screen space to be reduced when the keyboard pops up, causing the GeometryReader and its internal views to be re-layout. This rearrangement may interrupt ongoing animations.

However, this situation will not occur if you use the .animation modifier to define animations.

Effect:
[image: Effect picture]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var t: String = ""
  @State var appeared = 0
  let text = "rdvz"
  
  var horizontalSpacing: CGFloat {
    let textSize: CGSize = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Inter-Bold", size: 14.0)!])
    return textSize.width + 4
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        generateMarquee(with: geometry.size.width, spacing: horizontalSpacing)
          .frame(height: 20)
      }
      
      TextField("something to write", text: $t)
        .padding()
    }
    .onAppear(perform: animateMarquee)
  }
  
  private func generateMarquee(with width: CGFloat, spacing: CGFloat) -> some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0.0) {
      ForEach(0...Int(width / spacing) + 2, id: \.self) { index in
        Text("rdvz")
          .frame(width: spacing)
          .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold))
          .foregroundColor(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.secondary)
      }
    }
    .offset(x: appeared > 0 ? -spacing * 2 : 0)
    //Apply animation modifiers directly to this view
    .animation(.linear(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: appeared)
  }
  
  private func animateMarquee() {
    appeared = 1
  }
}


#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me either. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution using `TimelineView`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TickerView: View {
    @State var appeared = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        let text = "rdvz"
        let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Inter-Bold", size: 14.0)!])
        let horizontalSpacing = textSize.width + 4
        
        GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
            TimelineView(.animation(), content: { timeline in
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0.0) {
                    ForEach(0...Int(geometry.size.width / horizontalSpacing) + 2, id: \.self) {
                        index in
                        Text("rdvz")
                            .frame(width: horizontalSpacing)
                            .font(Font.DesignSystem.textSmBold)
                            .foregroundColor(index % 2 == 0 ? .fgSecondary700 : .fgTertiary600)
                    }
                    .offset(x: -timeline.date.timeIntervalSince1970.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0) * horizontalSpacing * 2.0)
                }
            })
        })
        .frame(height: textSize.height)
    }
}

#Preview {
    TickerView()
}
```